# How to remove 0s from an array and assign the values into a jagged array in C

Tags: c, arrays, jagged-arrays

My code initially fills a multi-dimentional int array([20][20]) with all zeros. Then it reads numbers from file and put it back into this array. It successfully puts the numbers from file. However, there are 0s that I can not get rid of.

I have checked the jagged array solutions online but I couldn't do it.

```
//fills the array
for( i = 0; i < 20 ; i++){
        for( j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                newString[i][j] = 0;
        }
}




j = 0;
ctr = 0;   //line number 
int m = 1,num = 1;
int spaceCounter = 0;
bool isMultiDigit = false;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
        for(i=0;i<=(strlen(line));i++){
                if(line[i]==' '){
                        spaceCounter++;
                }
                else if(line[i]=='\n'){
                        j = 0;

                }
                else{
                        if(line[i] != '\0'){
                                if(line[i+1] == ' ' || line[i+1] == '\n' || line[i+1] == '\0'){
                                        if(isMultiDigit){
                                                newString[ctr][j] = num;
                                                num = 1;
                                                isMultiDigit = false;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                                printf("line[i] = %c. \n", line[i]);
                                                newString[ctr][j] = line[i] - '0';
                                                printf("newString[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, newString[ctr][j]);
                                        }

                                        j++;
                                }
                                else{
                                        if(!isMultiDigit) num = (line[i]-'0') * 10 + (line[i+1] - '0') ;
                                        else num = num * 10 + (line[i+1] - '0') ;
                                        isMultiDigit = true;
                                }
                        }
                }
                spaceCounter = 0;
        }

        ctr++;

}


for( i = 0; i < 20 ; i++){
        for( j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                printf("%d ", newString[i][j]);
        }
        printf("-------\n");
}
```

Here is the content of file

```
3
9 3 34 4 12 5 2
6 3 2 7 1
256 3 5 7 8 9 1
```

Here is the output after filling zeros then reading from file

```
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
9 3 34 4 12 5 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
6 3 2 7 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
256 3 5 7 8 9 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -------
```

So in this case the new array, after getting rid of the 0s, would be

```
newArray[0] = {3} 
newArray[1] = {9, 3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2} 
newArray[2] = {6, 3, 2, 7, 1} 
newArray[3] = {256, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1}
```

Please provide code fragment to fix my problem. 
Thank yo

Comment: If you print out a 20x20 grid, what do you think happens when you don't have 20 elements in a line?

Comment: What do you think you should check to decide when to stop?

Comment: How should you stop a line when you decide to do that?

Comment: Do you want to print the `newArray` without zeros?

Answer (score 1):

After fixing your code, I got something like the below. I hope I got something that is almost correct. Nonetheless, there are a few points with your code. To assign all array index with a value of zero, you don't need to build that "for" loop. You can just do:

```
int newString[20][20] = { 0 };
```

For your case, you built a two-level int array of 20 by 20. C's arrays are not length flexible. Thus, all those arrays index will stay either if their values are zeroes or not. Thus, there is no way for you to remove those zeroes if you utilize that type of array. In your case, if you want to keep that style then you would have to validate values while printing. I changed the print block instead.

Other options you can look to in the future are an array of pointers to arrays that been located by malloc, or hashmap and similar data structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int newString[20][20] = { 0 };
    int j = 0;
    int m = 1,num = 1;
    int ctr = 0;   //line number
    int spaceCounter = 0;
    char line[999];
    bool isMultiDigit = false;
    FILE *fp;

    if ( (fp = fopen( "test.txt", "r" )) == NULL ){
        printf( "Could not open file" ) ;
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
        for( int i=0; i<=(strlen(line));i++ ){
            if(line[i]==' '){
                spaceCounter++;
            } else if(line[i]=='\n'){
                j = 0;
            } else{
                if(line[i] != '\0'){
                    if(line[i+1] == ' ' || line[i+1] == '\n' || line[i+1] == '\0'){
                        if(isMultiDigit){
                            newString[ctr][j] = num;
                            num = 1;
                            isMultiDigit = false;
                        } else{
                            printf("line[i] = %c. \n", line[i]);
                            newString[ctr][j] = line[i] - '0';
                             printf("newString[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, newString[ctr][j]);
                        }

                        j++;
                    } else {
                        if(!isMultiDigit) num = (line[i]-'0') * 10 + (line[i+1] - '0');
                        else num = num * 10 + (line[i+1] - '0') ;
                        isMultiDigit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            spaceCounter = 0;
        }
        ctr++;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++){
        if ( newString[i][0] == 0 ) continue;
        for( int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            if ( newString[i][j] != 0 ) printf("%d ", newString[i][j]);
        }
        printf("-------\n");
    }
}
```

I got some free time on hand. Thus, I included this second code, of which, utilized dynamical length int array. The code is almost exactly to your code, just different by the data type structure. Also, when you convert a char that you know for sure is an ASCII code of a digit to an int value, you can do "char ^ 48" instead of "char - '0'".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * An example of a data structure
 * that can hold dynamic length
 * int arrays. 
 */
struct arrayInt {
    int *value;
    int length;
    int size;
};

/*
 * Locating and return an array int structure
 * with its size and its value array to the de
 * defined size.
 */
struct arrayInt newArrayInt( const int size ){
    struct arrayInt output;
    output.value = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    output.length = 0;
    output.size = size;
    return output;
}

int main(void) {
    struct arrayInt newString[20];
    int j = 0;
    int m = 1,num = 1;
    int ctr = 0;   //line number
    int spaceCounter = 0;
    char line[999];
    bool isMultiDigit = false;
    FILE *fp;

    if ( (fp = fopen( "test.txt", "r" )) == NULL ){
        printf( "Could not open file" ) ;
        return 1;
    }

    // Locating dynamic length int arrays
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
        newString[i] = newArrayInt(20);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
        for( int i=0; i<=(strlen(line));i++ ){
            if(line[i]==' '){
                spaceCounter++;
            } else if(line[i]=='\n'){
                j = 0;
            } else{
                if(line[i] != '\0'){
                    if(line[i+1] == ' ' || line[i+1] == '\n' || line[i+1] == '\0'){
                        if(isMultiDigit){
                            newString[ctr].value[j] = num;
                            // Keep track of length
                            newString[ctr].length++;
                            num = 1;
                            isMultiDigit = false;
                        } else{
                            printf("line[i] = %c. \n", line[i]);
                            newString[ctr].value[j] = line[i] - '0';
                            // Keep track of length
                            newString[ctr].length++;
                             printf("newString[%d].value[%d] = %d\n", i,j, newString[ctr].value[j]);
                        }

                        j++;
                    } else {
                        if(!isMultiDigit) num = (line[i]-'0') * 10 + (line[i+1] - '0');
                        else num = num * 10 + (line[i+1] - '0') ;
                        isMultiDigit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            spaceCounter = 0;
        }
        ctr++;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++){
        if ( newString[i].length == 0 ) continue;
        for( int j = 0; j < newString[i].length; j++){
            printf("%d ", newString[i].value[j]);
        }
        printf("-------\n");
    }

    // free memory
    // Probably unnecessary.
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
        free(newString[i].value);
        newString[i].length = 0;
        newString[i].size = 0;
    }
}
```